# Symbol A after leader symbol in neovim

Tags: neovim

There is a shortcut `<leader>af`: code actions in lsp. When I hit space, then `A`, I turn into `insert mode`, and can't proceed typing `f`.
When I hit space, on bottom line I see `<leader>` record, so I assume, `space` is my `<leader>` key

Comment: It is not clear from your question if you typing _A_ or _a_, you have mapping for _<leader>af_ and typing _<leader>Af_, am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to understand how mappings works. I though I should get same mappings after installation instruction, but I didn't get the same. On my installation required mapping was `<leader>ca`